# How to read input username to drush script?

Tags: drush

I need to complete a script  which gets a username from terminal to a php script and then deletes the user's comments.

So I am wondering how the username should be read by the php script, the same way that one can read a value in a bash script.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Pass the script a user name on the command line or have the script asking you for the user name while it's running. If it's not to many users you could also show a list of users and let the administrator choose. Of course this options do not exclude each other.

Answer (score 4):

In your Drush command you need to call `drush_get_option('myoption');` to get the value of an input parameter.

To call your Drush command you need to specify your input option as below:

`drush mycommand --myoption=myvalue`

Answer (score 1):

there is an example command in the drush directory : http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-4.x:/examples/sandwich.drush.inc

in the command hook you define your arguments and those are then passed to the function that implements the command

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a drush command, you can call that via the command line and define arguments and switches.

You can easily then hook into drupal. as your function can run from a bootstrapped drupal instance.

Comment: I know that I should use drush. The problem is that how to define the STD input in the php/drush script.

Answer (score 0):

***In answer to the question by "alfish"***

I think the ultimate answer to this "old" question is to use PHP to control stdin.

```
function ask_user_name() {
  print("Please input your name: ");

  $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
  $line = fgets($handle);

  drush_print("Your name is $line");
}
```

Basically there was no need to establish an interface mechanism in drush since it already exists in php... but Drush does provide four commands anyway.

- drush_choice
- drush_choice_multiple
- drush_confirm
- drush_prompt

So in using drush_prompt you would do something like this.

```
function ask_user_name() {
  $result = drush_prompt("Please input your name",NULL,TRUE);
  drush_print("Your name is $result");
}
```

I hope this helps.